# setting chartjs global configuration using chartkick

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, chart.js, chartkick

I am unable to set global configuration for all of my chart types i.e linechart, bar chart e.t.c. Setting them as directed [here](https://www.chartkick.com/)
in config/initializers/chartkick.rb does not work.

I'd like to be able to access `Chart.defaults.global.elements` through chartkick so I can change the configuration for [line elements](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/elements.html)

i.e. set `curve: false` for linechart using the initializer other than setting it through the library option. Any help? Happy to show code samples

Answer (score 0):

For chart creation with charts.js, did you watch the gem 'groupdate'?

https://github.com/ankane/groupdate

Which then allows you to simply do:

```
<% = line_chart User.group_by_day(:created_at).count %>
```

Comment: Yes. I have. I already have my charts setup. I only need a way to change some of the options in one file instead of individually doing this:  `line_chart User.group_by_day(:created_at).count , curve: false ` everytime I create a linechart. Like is there a way to set options globally for all the charts?